# Does a system stay balanced after a perturbation?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Let's take the following example for concreteness:

I'm biking, and I stop at an intersection (not asking how bikes stay up while in motion). My feet are off the ground, and the center of mass (CM) of myself and the bike is perfectly over the wheels. Everything is at rest. 
Now, I move my right leg outward, to the right. Taking the point of contact of the wheels with the ground to be fixed...

Do I lose balance? If yes, which way do I fall? Does it depend? On what?

Let's say I start with the CM a little off to the left, then move my right leg out, which way do I fall?

Comment: You can probably answer that for yourself.  Imagine a 100 lb weight and a monkey at the top of a pole.  Let the monkey try to push the weight sideways.  Can the monkey move the center of gravity of the weight and himself by pushing sideways on the weight?   Now think about torques: the only way to move the c.g.of what's on top of the pole is to find a way to make the bottom of the pole push sideways on the ground.  Is there a way for the monkey to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "it depends."

First off, do realize that the human body breaks most introductory physics analysis.  Our bodies have so many higher order effects and feedback loops and whatnot that it's often very difficult to see the basic physics that underlie the body.  It obeys the laws of physics, its just really good at bending them.

That being said, the easiest way to keep track of what will happen in your bike situation is to use torque.  You say the point where the wheels contact the ground is fixed, which makes it a great origin.  We can look at how any of your moves torque around that point.

If you move your leg to the right, conservation of momentum says part of you moved to the left.  Which part?  If you moved lower extremities, that's very close to the center of your wheels, so the torque may be low and the movement of your leg to the right might cause the bike to torque around the wheel to the left.  On the other hand, if you moved hour head to the left to provide the momentum to move your leg to the right, that may cause the bike to torque to the right.

I mention your body cheats a bit.  You may not even be aware of the balancing you are doing when you put your foot out.  So you may be surprised when the results aren't what you expected.  You just weren't paying attention to the other half of the movement.

Now let's say you moved so that your center of mass is torqued to the left of the bike.  Now the situation is basically the second question you had.  At this point, gravity is actively pulling down on your center of mass, which is no longer in line with the wheels, so it applies a torque which will tip your bike over.  It is possible to move in a way which fixes this by moving your leg (and the rest of your body), or you can make it worse.  Skilled bicyclists know which is which.